# How do I import SoapUI project in Postman?

Tags: soapui, postman

Can anyone help me in importing the SoapUI project in postman?

I have imported wsdls in SoapUI. So I need a way to get the wsdls from SoapUi to postman or if there is a way to use wsdl files in postman directly it will help too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those two tools do not have a common format they can export to. The only common format between them is Swagger, which either of them can *import*. However, neither of them is able to *export* into this format.

Further, Postman is made with REST services in mind. As such, it cannot do anything with a WSDL. If you definitely must use Postman to test SOAP services, you will have to map all your calls as a POST call, unfortunately, all manually.

**Updates**:

I did little more digging. It seems that SoapUI is able to [import a Postman collection](https://www.soapui.org/docs/postman-collections.html).

And further, SoapUI is able to export a Swagger description: Project > Export Swagger.

Personally I have not tried either of these options.

Comment: Swagger doesn't work for SOAP projects "Project is missing REST APIs"

Comment: @Alberici That is correct, but Postman is not intended for SOAP either.

Comment: a little late but see this tutorial: https://blog.getpostman.com/2016/04/27/importing-soapui-projects-into-postman/

Answer (score 3):

Osiris is correct. Now we can at least import interfaces from SoapUI:

1. open SoapUI
2. select interface you want to export
3. in its context menu press "Export Definition" -> Save (it will be saved as wsdl and xsd files)
4. open Postman -> Import -> select saved wsdl and xsd files

Comment: This exports only the WSDL *definitions*, not the *requests* (body, parameters, ...) that are saved in the SoapUI project.

Answer (score 2):

From the previous comment, you can export and import collections and projects between Postman and SoapUI but only REST projects.

Exporting to Swagger in SoapUI will result in an error for a SOAP projects.

"[Importing SoapUI projects into Postman](https://blog.getpostman.com/2016/04/27/importing-soapui-projects-into-postman/)", referenced in the previous post, is referring to a REST Project not a SOAP project.

Answer (score 1):

After so much frustration, I installed a different tool called "SoapUI" by the SmartBear. IT worked very easily. I just gave it my wsdl url and it loaded all the end points.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Postman (8.4.0) supports importing WSDL files as Postman Collections.